# Select from bookmark to bookmark

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> in Notepad++, I set a bookmark at a line:

[image: Notepad++ screen shot]

When I press <kbd>F2</kbd> alone, I jump from bookmark to bookmark (always start of line).

Can I somehow *select* from bookmark to bookmark, eg. to replace the content of the loveletter in the screenshot in a fast and easy way?

Pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> just jumps backwards.

Comment: Why do you use bookmarks to change content? Why don't use regex? Explain clearly what you are trying to do, with text before and expected result.

Comment: @Toto: I am looking for a way to be able to not only *jump* from bookmark to bookmark but also to *select the text* from bookmark to bookmark. For example (!) to replace the content of the (exemplary) love letter, or to copy&paste a few lines of code while experimenting in a shell window.

Comment: I don't think it is possible :-( The workaround can be: mark all lines you want to copy, then, "copy Bookmarked lines"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To *select* from bookmark to bookmark,

1. Navigate to the first bookmark
2. Select Edit...Begin/End Select
3. Navigate to the next bookmark
4. Select Edit...Begin/End Select

The text in between the bookmarks should be highlighted.

Comment: Great! One can eg. configure `Ctrl`+`Space` to that function.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of. The marker you're referring to is a Bookmark. The Bookmark's menu only has the below-associated shortcut keys which are the shortcuts you're using.

[image]

I don't believe you can complement those shortcuts with additional keys to give you the expected behaviour.

Comment: Thank you, I've updated the question with the correct word. :-)

Comment: You're most welcome.